# How to form an object based on key from another array of object?

Tags: javascript

I want to form an object based the keys from another object and set values to empty string;

```
const availableList = [
  {id: 1, key: 'emp_id'},
  {id: 2, key: 'firstname'},
  {id: 3, key: 'lastname'},
  {id: 4, key: 'mobile'},
  {id: 5, key: 'email'},
]
    
availableList .forEach(key => result [key] = availableList [key]);
```

Expected output:

```
result = {
  emp_id: '', 
  firstname: '', 
  lastname: '', 
  mobile: '', 
  email: ''
}
```

Comment: Please provide a clear question. A question should always contain a question mark ;)

Comment: i have provided the available list expected output and what i have tried :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `.reduce` with object destructing and object's computed property

```js
const availableList = [
  { id: 1, key: "emp_id" },
  { id: 2, key: "firstname" },
  { id: 3, key: "lastname" },
  { id: 4, key: "mobile" },
  { id: 5, key: "email" },
]

const res = availableList.reduce(
  (finalObj, iteratedObj) => ({ ...finalObj, [iteratedObj.key]: "" }),
  {}
)

console.log(res)
```

**References**

[Array.property.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

[Destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

[Computed property names (ES 2015)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not very familiar with javascript, arrays and objects, it's probably better to keep it simple (avoid arrow functions and fancy es6 notation).

A simple [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) should do the trick:

```js
const availableList = [
    {id: 1, key: 'emp_id'},
    {id: 2, key: 'firstname'},
    {id: 3, key: 'lastname'},
    {id: 4, key: 'mobile'},
    {id: 5, key: 'email'},
];

var newObject = availableList.reduce(function (result, item) {
  result[item.key] = '';
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(newObject);
```

Some comments in case you're familiar with `Array#reduce`:

- The parameter I've named `result` is the value you use to "reduce" the array into a single variable.
- The parameter I've named `item` is the value of item of array during each iteration.
- The original value of `result` is the value specified as the second parameter of `reduce` (which in this case is `{}`)
- Inside the function passed to the `reduce`, you have to return the value that will be passed in as the `result` parameter in the next iteration
- So in each iteration, you get the object with they keys you've added up to that point, you add another key with a value of empty string and then return it so that it can be used for the next iteration.
- Once it's done iterating, it will return the last value, that was returned by the inside function. That value gets assigned to the variable `newObject`

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on it using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const availableList = [
  { id: 1, key: "emp_id" },
  { id: 2, key: "firstname" },
  { id: 3, key: "lastname" },
  { id: 4, key: "mobile" },
  { id: 5, key: "email" },
];

const result = Object.fromEntries(availableList.map((item) => [item.key, ""]))

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of properties. So as you suggested in your question, you need to use a forEach to iterate all the items. The items are objects in this case. So you can access all their properties just writing obj.property.

Let's see how can I add a property to an object.
I could do:

```
obj.property5 = 'something'
```

Or I could do:

```
obj['property5'] = 'something'
```

Since you have something unpredictable as the name of the property you should use the second one.
Here there's the code:

```
var secondObject = {};

availableList.forEach(function(item, index) {
  secondObject[item.key] = '';
});
```

Comment: Pretty good answer, but if the goal is to keep it simple, then shouldn't you remove the `index` parameter from the `Array#forEach` callback?

Comment: Yeah of course. I left it there because if someone doesn't know how it works he/she can understand better